# Concourse CI Job can not curl to Service on host machine get Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx. port 9090: No route to host

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, concourse

I have successful setup Concourse (5.7.1) on Ubuntu (16.04). Everything was find but after adding a script in deploy job to call an restful service running on same machine where concourse is installed, I got

`error:Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 9090: No route to host`

I have been able to call the restful service from other sources.
I intercept the Job and i was not able to make make a call to the service but I was able to ping external calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking this long to response. If someone else has the same problem. I succeeded to solve this problem by restarting my servers.

I don't know what exactly may had been the problem but restarting the servers works and it solved my problem.